# How to expose events in a WinForms custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I've developed a custom control that acts like a group box with a check box over the group label. The idea being, once the check box is unchecked all the controls in the group are disabled.

I need to expose the Check changed event so that external actions could be performed if required. I've also exposed the Check state changed.

Currently, when the control is used it changes the check state when any of the controls in the group loose focus.

When I handle the check changed event, should I then re-fire the event for any external handlers?

[image][image]

The events defined:

```
/// <summary>
/// Event to forward the change in checked flag
/// </summary>
public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

/// <summary>
/// Event to forward the change in checked state of the checkbox
/// </summary>
public event EventHandler CheckStateChanged;
```

The event handler code:

```
private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Disable the controls within the group
    foreach( Control ctrl in this.Controls )
    {
        if( ctrl.Name != "chkBox" && ctrl.Name != "lblDisplay" )
        {
            ctrl.Enabled = this.chkBox.Checked;
        }
    }

    // Now forward the Event from the checkbox
    if (this.CheckedChanged != null)
    {
        this.CheckedChanged(sender, e);
    }
}

private void chkBox_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Forward the Event from the checkbox
    if( this.CheckStateChanged != null )
    {
        this.CheckStateChanged( sender, e );
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks correct. Whats the problem?

Comment: When the user enters or changes any of the fields, the controls in the group get disabled. They then have to re-enable the group and move onto the next control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just have to register your event with a event handler in external class.

```
CheckedChanged += ExternalChkBox_CheckChanged;

private void ExternalChkBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // External trigger
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this in the code external to the control but I'm not convinced that the firing of the event is not causing the contained controls to be disabled.

Comment: @ TeamWild : I am not quite sure what your question is. Anyway, the code you have posted should be in the custom control class. And the code that I've written only should go to the external class. You should be able to enable/disable controls from the CustomControl class itself.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my current approach. I made the assumption that the group controls being disabled when one of the controls loose focus was because of the re-firing the of the check change event. I'll have to go back to the drawing board. :o/

Comment: @ TeamWild : Yes, I think you have to change the way it behaves.