# How to bind a custom control check box

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, checkbox, groupbox

I have been having issues with a custom check box control for a while now and had posted this [Question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092497/how-to-expose-events-in-a-winforms-custom-control) It appears that the problem isn't related to the events.

The custom control is a group box with a check box. When the check box is false, all the group controls should be disabled. It sounds simple but the problem is that when an internal control loses focus, the checked change event is fired.

After a bit more digging I think I have narrowed it down to the binding of the checked property to another object. When the binding is included it works incorrectly but with the binding removed everything works as expected.

I'm not sure how to resolve the issue now that it's been located.

**Can anyone help?**

Here is some code from my test application--

The Form:
[image]

The form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TestProperties m_TP;

    public Form1()
    {
        // Create instance of TestProperties
        m_TP = new TestProperties();

        InitializeComponent();

        BindControls();
    }

    private void BindControls()
    {
        // Bind the values to from the controls in the group to the properties class

        // When the line below is commented out the control behaves normally
        //this.checkedGroupBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", m_TP, "GroupChecked");
        this.numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", m_TP, "SomeNumber");
        this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "SomeText");
        this.checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", m_TP, "BoxChecked");

        // Bind the values of the properties to the lables
        this.label4.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "GroupChecked");
        this.label5.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "SomeNumber");
        this.label6.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "SomeText");
        this.label8.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "BoxChecked");
    }
}
```

A property storage class:

```
class TestProperties
{
    public bool GroupChecked { get; set; }
    public decimal SomeNumber { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public bool BoxChecked { get; set; }

    public TestProperties()
    {
        GroupChecked = false;
        SomeNumber = 0;
        SomeText = string.Empty;
        BoxChecked = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Here is the source for my custom control:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom control to create a checked group box.
/// Enables / disables all controls within the group depending upon the state of the check box
/// </summary>
public class CheckedGroupBox : System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
{
    #region Private Member Variables
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Checkbox to enable / disable the controls within the group
    /// </summary>
    private CheckBox chkBox;

    /// <summary>
    /// Label for the group box which is set to autosize
    /// </summary>
    private Label lblDisplay;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    ///  Default constructor for the control
    /// </summary>
    public CheckedGroupBox()
    {
        // This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent();

        // The text of these controls should always be empty.
        this.Text = "";
        this.chkBox.Text = "";
    }

    #region Events & Delegates

    /// <summary>
    /// Event to forward the change in checked flag
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event to forward the change in checked state of the checkbox
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CheckStateChanged;

    private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable the controls within the group
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Name != "chkBox" && ctrl.Name != "lblDisplay")
            {
                ctrl.Enabled = this.chkBox.Checked;
            }
        }

        // Now forward the Event from the checkbox
        if (this.CheckedChanged != null)
        {
            this.CheckedChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void chkBox_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Forward the Event from the checkbox
        if (this.CheckStateChanged != null)
        {
            this.CheckStateChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.chkBox = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.lblDisplay = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // chkBox
        // 
        this.chkBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 0);
        this.chkBox.Name = "chkBox";
        this.chkBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16);
        this.chkBox.TabIndex = 0;
        this.chkBox.CheckStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.chkBox_CheckStateChanged);
        this.chkBox.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.chkBox_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // lblDisplay
        // 
        this.lblDisplay.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblDisplay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 0);
        this.lblDisplay.Name = "lblDisplay";
        this.lblDisplay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 13);
        this.lblDisplay.TabIndex = 1;
        this.lblDisplay.Text = "CheckedGroupBox";
        // 
        // CheckedGroupBox
        // 
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
        this.Controls.Add(this.chkBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblDisplay);
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
    #endregion

    #region Public properties

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue("Check Group Text")]
    public override string Text
    {
        get{ return this.lblDisplay.Text; }
        set{ this.lblDisplay.Text = value; }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue("Checked")]
    public System.Windows.Forms.CheckState CheckState
    {
        get{ return this.chkBox.CheckState; }
        set
        { 
            this.chkBox.CheckState = value; 

            foreach( Control ctrl in this.Controls )
            {
                if( ctrl.Name != "chkBox" && ctrl.Name != "lblDisplay" )
                {
                    ctrl.Enabled = this.chkBox.Checked;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue("True")]
    public bool Checked
    {
        get{ return this.chkBox.Checked; }
        set
        { 
            this.chkBox.Checked = value; 

            foreach( Control ctrl in this.Controls )
            {
                if( ctrl.Name != "chkBox" && ctrl.Name != "lblDisplay" )
                {
                    ctrl.Enabled = this.chkBox.Checked;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Behavior"), DefaultValue("False")]
    public bool ThreeState
    {
        get{ return this.chkBox.ThreeState; }
        set{ this.chkBox.ThreeState = value; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: "...when an internal control loses focus, the checked change event is fired."  I think you need to just focus on that and not worry about the databinding at this moment.

Comment: What does the code look like that you are using to update m_TP when the values in the controls change?

Comment: @Veldmuis - The BindControls method shows how I update the properties. I've just added the code for the custom control for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the BindControls method as follows.  The reason for this is that by default the controls are being updated to reflect the properties of m_TP, but when their values are changed the changes aren't being reflected in m_TP (I guess that the Leave events cause a rebinding of the controls to their datasources).  By adding the DataSourceUpdateMode parameter the changes will be made bidirectionally.

```
private void BindControls()
{
    // Bind the values to from the controls in the group to the properties class

    // When the line below is commented out the control behaves normally
    this.checkedGroupBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", m_TP, "GroupChecked", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    this.numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", m_TP, "SomeNumber", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "SomeText", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    this.checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", m_TP, "BoxChecked", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    // Bind the values of the properties to the lables
    this.label4.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "GroupChecked");
    this.label5.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "SomeNumber");
    this.label6.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "SomeText");
    this.label8.DataBindings.Add("Text", m_TP, "BoxChecked");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. That's cracked it.

Answer (score 1):

First, in order for your binding to work properly you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your property storage class.  Please see an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

In your Visual Studio environment create a new DataSource pointing to type "Object". Select your TestProperties class as source object (if the class does not show up in the list make sure you have built the containing assembly and your WinForm project has a reference to it).

[image: Data Source Configuration Wizard]

Now, drag a BindingSource from your Toolbox onto your custom control.  Set the DataSource property of the BindingSource to TestProperties data source you created in the previous step.

Now, select the custom control groupbox and go to the (DataBindings) section.  Click the "..." in the advanced field.  Bind the "Enabled" property of your custom grid control to the "BoxChecked" property of the BindingSource.  This can all be done in the designer (or through code behind if you prefer)

[image]

Bind the other WinForms elements on the custom control to the appropriate elements of the TestProperties class through the BindingSource.

Now, expose a property on the custom control so you can bind to it in the "parent" form.  Make sure you set the "DataSource" of the BindingSource to the newly reference property.

```
    private TestProperties _properties;
    public TestProperties Properties
    {
        get { return _properties; }
        set
        {
            _properties = value;
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = _properties;
        }
    }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In your parent form which is hosting the control you have a couple of options.

1)  You can perform the binding directly to the TestProperties class exposed by the UserControl as you have in your above example

2)  You can repeat the BindingSource exercise that you used to setup binding on the user control on the parent control and set the DataSource property of the new BindingSource (on the parent form) to equal the exposed TestProperties property of the UserControl.

Comment: I think I have followed you correctly but I still get the same problem. Should TestProperties be exposed in the custom control? I can't do this as the control needs to work with all sorts of different property classes based on the requirements of the parent form.

Comment: Instead of exposing a property of type TestProperties you could expose an Interface implemented by all "Property" classes or a "PropertyBase" class which your custom PropertyClasses inherit from

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is as close as I could get:

[image]

I obviously don't have the code for the groupbox (with checkbox included) so I made do with what I could.

This is achieved by adding this to the top checkbox:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   groupBox1.Enabled = ((CheckBox)(sender)).Checked;
}
```

I also re-enabled this line:

```
this.checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", m_TP, "GroupChecked");
```

Comment: I have added the source for the custom control. I think the problem relates to binding rather than events. The control works as required when the binding is removed.